# How to configure NDK for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3

I've installed Android Studio 2.2.3 and created a "myApplication" with `include C++ support`. 
I get this error:

*Error:NDK not configured.

Download it with SDK manager.)*

Is there any good way to solve it please?

Comment: Is it impossible? Hasn't anyone done it on the planet earth?

Comment: You did not say what you did in order to solve it - did you download the NDK? Did you tell your Android Studio where it is after you downloaded it?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded and installed *android-ndk-r13b* but how to tell it where it is? And also the NDK section does not exist in my Android Studio!!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Once you have downloaded the NDK, go to "File" menu, than "Project Structure->SDK Location" and set the Android NDK Location (it is at the bottom of the window).

Comment: I entered the path "**C:\Users\CS\Desktop\Documents\Andro\android-ndk-r13b**" there. Now I get: "**Error:Failed to find CMake.
Install from Android Studio under File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake.
Expected CMake executable at C:\Users\CS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe.**". Should I run that *cmake.exe* in its path?

Comment: OK, so it means now you have the NDK ready. You are facing another issue - if you haven't already, I suggest you look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

Comment: If you mean **LLDB**, **CMake**, and **NDK,**, they don't exist on my Android Studio! Please [look](http://imgur.com/a/ZoBm5).

Comment: Try to open standalone Android SDK Manager (there is a link at the bottom of the SDK window from where you took the screenshot) and go to Packages menu -> Reload. See if that helps.

Comment: I did this. No new packages were downloaded or installed! Please look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW0PR.jpg).

Comment: Thanks man. Using patience and creativity, the issue was solved. And your help was also considerable. (+1 and answer vote).

Comment: Good - I am very glad to hear that.